# Clarification of Logical Operators in a PostGIS Database

Tags: postgis, sql

The following query returns this result:

```
select count(*) from a , b where a.geom && b.geom;

     count 
    -------
     66514
```

On a postgis 2 database.

What does the logical operator AND (&&) between two geometry columns return?

What about the other operators?

**Edit: After a quick test it seems it returns all the rows where the bounding boxes of both the geometries overlap with each other**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Array Functions and Operators** (Postgres vs PostGIS)

edit:  `Returns TRUE if A's 2D bounding box intersects B's 2D bounding box.`

[image]

[image]

**Postgres Operator**
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-array.html

**Postgis Operators**
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/reference.html#Operators

Comment: See http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/reference.html#Operators for a PostGIS specific operator explanation.