# PostGIS : Does the <-> operator work for Geography?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type

With the recent PostgreSQL/PostGIS version, you can now use the `<->` operator to find the nearest rows to a point: 
 [Indexed Nearest Neighbour Search in PostGIS](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/)

According to my tests, this query:

```
SELECT name, gid
FROM geonames
ORDER BY geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,40),4326)
LIMIT 10;
```

is the same precision and a bit slower than if I use the PostgreSQL Point type.

I would like to use this new operator with the **Geography** type to do better calculus on a spheroid. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the <-> operator is not defined on geography. You can use the geometry operator and a cast to geography on the resultants

```
ST_Distance(geom::geography, ST_GeogFromText(''))
```

to get the final distances, but potentially if your objects are over the poles or dateline or in the far north the initial geometry ordering of <-> won't be correct so things won't work perfectly.

Comment: 8 years later i come back here, now postgis support opperator <-> with geography, and it's super fast !!

Answer (score 3):

**You can use ST_DWithin with geography in PostGIS**

```
--Find the nearest hospital to each school
--that is within 3000 units of the school.
-- We do an ST_DWithin search to utilize indexes to limit our search list
-- that the non-indexable ST_Distance needs to process
--If the units of the spatial reference is meters then units would be meters
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.gid) s.gid, s.school_name, s.the_geom, h.hospital_name
    FROM schools s
        LEFT JOIN hospitals h ON ST_DWithin(s.the_geom, h.the_geom, 3000)
    ORDER BY s.gid, ST_Distance(s.the_geom, h.the_geom);

--The schools with no close hospitals
--Find all schools with no hospital within 3000 units
--away from the school.  Units is in units of spatial ref (e.g. meters, feet, degrees)
SELECT s.gid, s.school_name
    FROM schools s
        LEFT JOIN hospitals h ON ST_DWithin(s.the_geom, h.the_geom, 3000)
    WHERE h.gid IS NULL;
```

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find more information about the logical operators of postgis in another question:

[Clarification of Logical Operators in a PostGIS Database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34997/clarification-of-logical-operators-in-a-postgis-database)